# how do I solve Assert.Is.True (it's not meant to be False btw) failed in my Test Driven Development

Tags: c#

I am setting up a data layer using Test Driven Development and at the moment I am on the 'FindMethodOK' but It will not pass due to Assert.Is.True failing. Any Help will be appreciated.

```
//create an instance of the class we want to create
clsPhoneCustomer APhoneCustomer = new clsPhoneCustomer();

//boolean variable to store the result of the validation 
Boolean Found = false;

//create some test data to use with the method 
int CustomerID = 1;

//invoke the method 
Found = APhoneCustomer.Find(CustomerID);

//test to see that the result is correct 
Assert.IsTrue(Found);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! See if you can edit your question and surround your code with a code block so it's easier to read. It's not really possible to help you without seeing the contents of the Find method. Also one of your comments mentions creating test data but it seems you haven't done that.

Comment: Side note: your capitalization style is roughly opposite of standard one (lowcase variable names, upper case class names)

Answer (score 0):

Red test is good.

Now to make it green you need to add *minimal* implementation - one option is just always return true:

```
class clsPhoneCustomer
{
    public bool Find(int id) { return true;}
}
```

Now test is green, you can add more tests that confirm that ID is actually used.